# Entity Framework backup database - Operating system error 53 (The network path was not found.)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-backups

I am trying to create a backup using the following code:

```
public bool BackupDataBase(string filename)
{
        MinisterioDeportesEntityDataModel modeloMinisterio = new MinisterioDeportesEntityDataModel();
        modeloMinisterio.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, @"BACKUP DATABASE [db9ce858d6b9cb47658934a46901350226] TO  DISK = 'D:\Users\octa8_000\Documents\ISW\BackUp'  ");
        return true;
}
```

but it returns the following message:

> Operating system error 53 (The network path was not found)

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well, from the error, it doesn't seem like your database can find 'D:\Users\octa8_000\Documents\ISW\BackUp'.

Comment: the data base is upload to a webService, can't I make a backup locally, on my PC?

Comment: Unless the database server can access your PC somehow, I don't see how that's possible.